# Can't get the value of input file

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

**It's working now**

I'm using laravel and i have a form with an input file to upload some pictures, the problem is i want to render the image before upload and i make some changes on style.

My code looks like here:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
            <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="" id="img2" class="img2" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
            <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;"><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar header" id="browse_file" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar home" id="browse_file2" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
```

And my JS code looks like here:

```
$("#browse_file").on('click',function(e){
    $("#pathheader").click();
})

$("#browse_file2").on('click',function(e){
    $("#pathhome").click();
})

$("#pathheader").on('change',function(e){
    var fileInput=this;
    if (fileInput.files[0])
        {
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function(e)
            {
                $("#img").attr('src',e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        }
})

$("#pathhome").on('change',function(e){
    var fileInput=this;
    if (fileInput.files[0])
        {
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function(e)
            {
                $("#img2").attr('src',e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        }
})
```

As you can see, i have inputs with style display none, but i work with this inputs in the controller, controller looks like here:

```
public function storeProject(Request $request)
{
    $project = new Project();
    $project->slug = $request->input("slug");
    //$project->order = $request->input("order");
    $project->order = DB::table('projects')
                  ->where('order', DB::raw("(select max(`order`) from projects)"))
                  ->first()
                  ->order + 1; 
    $project->public = $request->input("public");
    $project->pathheader = $request->file('pathheader');
    $project->pathhome = $request->file('pathhome');
    \Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
    \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathheader,'header.png');
    \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathhome,'home.png');
    $project->save();
}
```

In the line of  `\Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathheader,'header.png');`

`$project->pathheader` don't have any value, same in pathhome.

How to get the value with a `display: none;`?

If don't understand something, or need more information, please ask it.

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you dumped `$request->all()` ? What is the values of pathheader and pathname ?

Comment: And also, Can you add your whole form ?

Comment: Set them to visibility:hidden instead. The fields will not be sent to the server with display:none, but will be with visibility:hidden.

Comment: @SagarGautam Hi mate, i think i have maybe an error with gulp or something. I just try it now 5 times and it works.. Anyway, i think buttons don't look really good in the form, know how to make it only with the <img> ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gerard it sends it with display:none! thanks anyway!